# C# - IEnumerable to delimited string

Tags: c#, functional-programming

What is the functional programming approach to convert an `IEnumerable<string>` to a delimited string?  I know I can use a loop, but I'm trying to wrap my head around functional programming.

Here's my example:

```
var selectedValues =
from ListItem item in checkboxList.Items
where item.Selected
select item.Value;

var delimitedString = ??
```

.. or could I do this in just the first var assignment (append each result to the previous)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var delimitedString = selectedValues.Aggregate((x,y) => x + ", " + y);
```

Comment: That will be very expensive in terms of intermediate strings. Very FP, but not very practical.
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: @Marc, I answered the question asked, it was about FP, not about performance.

Answer (score 40):

```
string.Join(", ", string[] enumerable)
```

Comment: @Lucas, not if you're using .NET 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx

Comment: @Omer, true! but this was back in Oct 2008, before .NET 4 :)

Answer (score 24):

Here's an example with a `StringBuilder`. The nice thing is that `Append()` returns the `StringBuilder` instance itself.

```
  return list.Aggregate( new StringBuilder(), 
                               ( sb, s ) => 
                               ( sb.Length == 0 ? sb : sb.Append( ',' ) ).Append( s ) );
```

Comment: last line should probably be ( sb.Length == 0 ? sb.Append(s) : sb.Append( ',' ) ).Append( s ) );

Answer (score 4):

```
var delimitedString = string.Join(",", checkboxList.Items.Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

AviewAnew is the best answer, but if what you are looking for is learning how to think in functional, what you should do is use a fold operation (or aggregate as it is called in NET).

```
items.Aggregate((accum, elem) => accum + ", " + elem);
```

Comment: Is string.join better for performance reasons?  I would say it is better from a readability stand-point.

Comment: I'd say yes; .ToArray() [to get the string[]] will use doubling, so not many intermediate arrays - and then string.Join is essentially StringBuilder; however, string concatenation will have a new string each time, so telescoping in size.

Comment: Agree, this is the kind of solution you would find in a functional programming language (such as haskell), but not here. But grasping foldr is one of the keys to master functional languages.

Comment: So, is this an example of why functional languages are not generally as performant?

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this case the functional approach might not be best suited, simply because there isn't a LINQ "ForEach", and you don't want to use string concatenation: you want to use StringBuilder. You could use ToArray (an example just appeared above), but I'd be tempted to simply use:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(ListViewItem item in checkboxList.SelectedItems) {
        if(sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(',');
        sb.Append(item.Text);
    }
    string s = sb.ToString();
```

Not functional programming, but it works... of course, if your source is *already* a string[] then string.Join is perfect.
(LINQ is a great tool, but not necessarily always the best tool for every job)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LINQ/functional way of doing it.

```
string[] toDelimit = CallSomeFunction();
return toDelimit.Aggregate((x, y) => x + "," + y);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 3.5 compatible:

```
var selectedValues = String.Join(",", (from ListItem item in checkboxList.Items where item.Selected select item.Value).ToArray());
```